# Shapefile has multiple "maps" in R

Tags: shapefile, r-raster

I am fairly new to using shapefiles in R.
I downloaded a shapefile of Africa and imported it into R.
`africa<-st_read(paste0(shape_file_directory, "africa_map/afr_g2014_2013_0.shp"))`

I then wanted to check out how the shapefile looks.

`plot(africa)`

Somehow the shapefiles includes multiple maps of Africa?:

[shapefile maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtnNG.jpg)

I just want a simple outline of Africa and its countries.

Sorry if this is a trivial question and let me know if you need any more info.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default `plot.sf` will create one plot for each attribute (non-geometry column) in a spatial data frame. You can choose a single attribute to plot or show just the geometry by changing the data you pass to `plot`. See this vignette for details:
https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf5.html